# On a Drupal user application form, is it possible for the user to lookup existing users?

Tags: users

I'm looking to add a user lookup form to my Drupal site's application form. One question would ask the applicant/registrant to look up an already existing user on the site. What's the best way to go about something like this in Drupal?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. What do you mean by "look up" in this context? A search system? A list?

Comment: @cilefen I have a group of existing users who are displayed as a view (to the public). Users are on that View if they have a user role checked. So I want the 'look up' autocomplete a user (first name, last name) from that list. 

It's a way of the registration giving the applicant the ability to say who (of the users on the site) referred them to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but would require some custom code.

Assuming you already have a form element where your autocomplete search would take place, in a `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` you could use something like:

```
  // Add ajax autocomplete.
  $form['name_of_your_text_element']['#attached']['js'][] = 'misc/autocomplete.js';
  $form['name_of_your_text_element']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'ctools/autocomplete/user';
```

Note that you will probably need to adjust some permissions in order to allow anonymous users to see your users' information. Check /admin/people/permissions if you need to fine-tune something there.

You also need to have the ctools module enabled in order to use this functionality.